# Access 2016 Compact and repair bloating

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to compact and repair an Access Database (MS Access 2016). I did it several times in the past already, but this time, the compact and repair procedure is hanging. When i look at the temporary Database.mdb generated, I see that it hit 2 097 152 Kb. This is really strange as my uncompacted DB is only about 100 Mb.

Does anyone have a clue ?
Thank you,

Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new blank database, and try importing everything from the older one.

Also, don't try to compact + repair say on a network shared folder. Copy the accDB file local, and then do the c+r.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes in the end, i copy pasted everything in a new blank DB and it solved my issue.

Comment: Better to use the import - not copy paste. But, all good.